# Does a derived class inherit the forward declarations used by the base class?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, declaration, forward

I have a linked list program where the TailNode class inherits from the Node class and both classes use a Data class parameter. Data has already been forward declared in my Node class header, but I don't understand why my program runs fine even though I haven't forward declared Data in my TailNode derived class header.

Do derived classes also inherit forward declarations used by the base class? What am I missing here?

Here are my two headers Node and TailNode...

**Node.h**

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

class Data;    //forward declaration

class Node
{
public:
    Node(){}
    virtual ~Node(){}
    virtual Node* Insert(Data *theData) = 0;
    virtual void Show() = 0;
};

#endif
```

**TailNode.h**

```
#ifndef TAILNODE_H
#define TAILNODE_H

class TailNode : public Node
{
public:
    TailNode(){}
    ~TailNode(){}
    virtual Node* Insert(Data *theData);
    virtual void Show() { }
};

#endif

//TailNode inherits everything from Node and seems to not need Data forward declared maybe because it was already forward declared for Node class?
```

Comment: Presumably you `#included` Node.H in (or before) TailNode.h, otherwise it wouldn't have compiled at all.

Comment: Do you need the rest of the code to know why this is happening? I didn't want to spam all my code if I didn't have to.

Comment: Note that if TailNode.h really doesn't `#include "Node.H"`, it's a broken header file: it only works if the files that include it have first included Node.h.  Best practice is to `#include` or forward declare all the declarations a header file depends on, so that it can be included alone and/or in any order.  (Forward declaring `Node` in TailNode.h isn't an option because you can't inherit an incomplete class.)

Comment: Thank you, this answers my other question I was going to ask!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there is absolutely no connection between `class Data` and `class Node` whatsoever, other than they happen to be in the same header file.

Header files are to make sharing declarations easy, but they exist *entirely* for your convenience.  They have no effects whatsoever on the code contained in them.  Let me see if I can clarify with an example:

apple.h

```
class Data;

class Node
{
public:
    Node(){}
    virtual ~Node(){}
    virtual Node* Insert(Data *
```

banana.h

```
theData) = 0;
    virtual void Show() = 0;
}; 

class TailNode : public Node
{
public:
    TailNode(){}
    ~TailNode(){}
    virtual Node* Insert(Data *theData);
    virtual void Show() { }
};
```

mycode.cpp

```
#include "apple.h"
#include "banana.h"

int main() {
}
```

The `#include` inside `mycode.cpp` effectively copy-pastes whatever is in that file into `mycode.cpp`.  Since the copy-pasted code is valid:

```
class Data;

class Node
{
public:
    Node(){}
    virtual ~Node(){}
    virtual Node* Insert(Data *theData) = 0;
    virtual void Show() = 0;
}; 

class TailNode : public Node
{
public:
    TailNode(){}
    ~TailNode(){}
    virtual Node* Insert(Data *theData);
    virtual void Show() { }
};

int main() {
}
```

Then the program is valid, and works fine!

Comment: Thank you for giving a good kick to the back of my head. I got lost in all the code that I forgot the order in which the header files were actually being included in.

Comment: @user3935153: For small projects, it's usually best to include the appropriate header files.  For large projects that take a long time to compile, forward declarations are sometimes better.  What's important is that you make sure that if I add a cpp file that headers include whatever they need, and should never require that another header be included first.